# Is it possible to get a bounding box for the rectangular region of unmasked pixels in an Image in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm working with the 2019 Hansen Global Forest Change Image:

```
var gfcImg = ee.Image("UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2019_v1_7");
```

Even though every band of `gfcImg` is masked everywhere above about 80° latitude and below about -57° latitude, `gfcImg.geometry()` covers the entire planet. I need a bounding box in the form of a Geometry which encloses only the rectangular region between these latitudes in which `gfcImg` isn't masked. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reduceToVector for this:

```
var gfcImg = ee.Image("UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2019_v1_7");

Map.addLayer(gfcImg, {}, 'gfc')

var roi = ee.Geometry.BBox(-180, -89.5, 180, 89.5)

var bounds = gfcImg.select("treecover2000").mask().gt(0).selfMask().addBands(1).reduceToVectors({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first(), 
  geometry: roi, 
  scale: 500, 
  geometryType: "bb",
  maxPixels: 1e13
})
print(bounds)
```

You want the pixels with mask > 0, and you want to exclude the pixels with mask == 0 (`.selfmask()`). You have to provide another band (`.addBands(1)`), just because the reducer needs something to do.

The result is a `FeatureCollection`

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably looking for something like this:

```
// above about 80° latitude and below about -57° latitude
var bounds = ee.Geometry.Rectangle({coords:[-180, -57, 180, 80],  geodesic: false});
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a2ed061eb9b38f1b9525b54589380540)

Comment: Thanks, @Kuik. This works for this case, but I'm looking for a general solution in which these coordinates are derived from the Image.